# JQuery plugin to display and edit Trees using a closure table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, transitive-closure-table

I have a tree structure in an `SQL` database and I'm looking to display and edit it via web pages using `Javascript`, `PHP` and `MYSQL`.

I can't seem to find any plugins that meet my needs. I would like to be able to add new nodes into the tree, edit and delete them.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Any recommendations or input would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Not sure it would be supported out of the box, but I'm sure with some coding you would be able to achieve it with this library: http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/index.php#tree

Comment: Thanks. I decided on jsPlumb though. http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/jquery.html